# To show the help related information in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have several dialogs in the application. I want to pop up help related box when user clicks on the help button next to Main Heading.

The help box is activated by selecting the small blue icon next to the heading. When the help box appears it has the information that is required to understand the entry related to the dialog.

This help box automatically disappears when user clicks any where other then the help box.

Please help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a Popup object, this should solve the problem:

http://www.designerwpf.com/2007/12/11/getting-the-popup-to-close-when-it-loses-focus/